# Casting numeric from character imprecision

Tags: r

`as.numeric(as.character(1363821605424526000))` results in `1363821605424526080`.

Why and how do I prevent this?

Comment: Read up on floating point precision and study `help(".Machine")`.

Comment: @Roland So there is no `long` in R that I can use? It doesn't get messed up if it's a factor in a data.frame or data.table. Only cast from string or read.csv.

Comment: Not in base R (see `help("typeof")`). There might be some packages that could help and of-course, depending on what you'd like to do with these numbers, you could write something yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to use the `gmp` library (**GNU Multiple Precision** library) to create and do basic arithmetic  with big integers...

```
require(gmp)
as.bigz("1363821605424526000")
#Big Integer ('bigz') :
#[1] 1363821605424526000
```

Note the use of `"` round the number. This is to protect it from being parsed as a `numeric` data type by R which of course will not be able to represent this number exactly in the given data structures. `"` gets R to treat it as a character variable before `as.bigz` turns it into a `big integer` type.

#### Examples

```
as.bigz("1363821605424526000") + 1
#Big Integer ('bigz') :
#[1] 1363821605424526001

as.bigz("1363821605424526000")^3
#Big Integer ('bigz') :
#[1] 2536720967038413127881466345733319337545403576000000000
```